# How to create non-admin account in windows xp with specifically limited rights?

Tags: windows-xp, file-management, file-permissions, limited-user-account

I am an Administrator of a PC with Windows XP and I want to create non-admin account in order to hide folders and files which I don't want to share. Please explain how to do it. I never did it before.

Answer (score 0):

> The partition must be an NTFS partition.

Right click the folder, select properties, security.

Remove permissions for everyone, then add Full Control for just the users that should access the folder.

> You may have to disable inheritance in the Advanced screen.